# Failure of Blumenthal's 0-1 law for non Feller processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

What is an example of an right continuous Markov process (in the sense of semigroups) that fails the Blumenthal $0-1$ law? One may assume necessary regularity assumptions on the underlying probability space, and choose the space in which the process takes values in. Though I would prefer if it were something simple like $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: For example, $X_t = t$ with probability $\tfrac12$, and $X_t = -t$ with probability $\tfrac12$ is Markovian, but obviously does not satisfy the Blumenthal 0–1 law. (Here the starting point is $0$; when started at $x > 0$, we simply have $X_t = x + t$, while if started at $x < 0$, we have $X_t = x - t$.)

Comment: Thanks for the illustrative example! I am probably missing something obvious, but which property of the Feller process definition does this fail? It seems to satisfy the continuity property since functions in $C_0 (\mathbb R)$ are uniformly continuous.

Comment: Here $p_tf(x) = f(x+t)$ for $x > 0$ and $p_tf(x) = f(x-t)$ for $x < 0$, so $p_tf$ need not be continuous at zero.

Comment: Ahh, I was checking that $p_t f \to f$ in the sup norm, but didn’t notice that the$ p_t f $themselves are not necessarily continuous. Thanks!